# Settings - Date Preferences - mailing - start offset, end offset (what do they mean?)

Tags: mailing, settings, preferences

Please can someone explain what the **start offset** and **end offset** fields mean in Settings - Date Preferences - mailing. The default values are 0 and 1 respectively. I feel it should understand this, but I don't. Am I an idiot? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm an idiot. The start offset means that users can't schedule mailings in the past, and the 1 means that they can schedule mailings up to one year into the future.

Maybe "offset" isn't the ideal word. "Start of valid range" and "End of valid range" would be clearer.